# R6010- Abort gets hit when rename or copy_file method of boost filesystem gets hit

Tags: c++, file, boost

Description:
I am trying to move all the files in a directory to a certain(user choosen directory)based on their extension to a certain directory via boost file system.
Problem:
When the rename/copy_file method of boost filesystem gets hit,I am receiving the R6010-Abort method called error.
Example:

```
SourceDirectory:C:\Source\a.txt
DestinationDirectory:C:\Destination
```

After execution:

```
DestinationDirectory:C:\Destination\a.txt
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include "boost/filesystem/operations.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
#include "boost/progress.hpp"

#include "boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void categorizeFolder()
{
    //Source Folder
    std::string folderToCategorize;
    cout<<"Choose the folder you want to categorize:";
    cin>>folderToCategorize;
    cout << "The directory you have choosen is: " << folderToCategorize << endl;

    //Destination folder
    std::string newfolder;
    cout<<"Choose the folder you want to store your files:";
    cin>>newfolder;
    cout << "The directory you have choosen is: " << newfolder << endl;

    std::vector< std::string > all_matching_files;
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr; 

    for( boost::filesystem::directory_iterator i( folderToCategorize ); i != end_itr;     ++i )
    {
        if( !boost::filesystem::is_regular_file( i->status() ) ) continue;          
        if( i->path().extension() == ".txt"  ) 
        {
            cout<<i->path().extension();//Printing File extension
            cout<<i->path();//Printing file path
            cout<<i->path().filename()<<endl;   //Printing filename
            fs::rename(i->path(), newfolder);//This would move the     file//Even tried fs::copy_file(i->path(), newfolder)                                         
        }

    }
}
```

Kindly let me know if i am missing something in the above code.Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linux error looks like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::rename: Is a directory: "/tmp/first/test.txt", "/tmp/second"
```

The fact that the API call is named `rename` and not, e.g. `moveToFolder`, should have given you an idea that you need to supply a full pathname in the target.

```
fs::rename(
     it->path(), 
     fs::path(newfolder) / it->path().filename());
```

to fix it.

Here's a version with some better organization and error handling. It will even create the target directory if it doesn't already exist!

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void categorizeFolder(fs::path folderToCategorize, fs::path newfolder)
{
    if (!fs::exists(newfolder))
        fs::create_directories(newfolder);

    if (!fs::is_directory(newfolder))
    {
        std::cerr << "Destination folder does not exist and could not be created: " << fs::absolute(newfolder) << "\n";
        return;
    }

    for(fs::directory_iterator it(folderToCategorize), end_itr; it != end_itr; ++it)
    {
        if(!fs::is_regular_file(it->status())) 
            continue;          
        if(it->path().extension() == ".txt") 
        {
            // std::cout << it->path().extension() << "\n";
            // std::cout << it->path()             << "\n";
            // std::cout << it->path().filename()  << "\n";
            fs::rename(it->path(), fs::path(newfolder) / it->path().filename()); // move the file
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc<3)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " folderToCategorize newfolder\n";
        return 255;
    }

    std::string const folderToCategorize = argv[1];
    std::string const newfolder = argv[2];

    std::cout << "The directory you have choosen is: " << folderToCategorize << endl;
    std::cout << "The directory you have choosen is: " << newfolder << endl;

    categorizeFolder(folderToCategorize, newfolder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I missed in the second argument to the rename method of boost fs.